# Render Array of Objects in React Native Flatlist

Tags: react-native

Im currently having trouble with rendering an arary of objects into my react native flatlist.

This is my array:

```
const item = [
{
  "id": 59,
  "id_order": Object {
    "created": "23/08/2021 16:37:55",
    "direccion_extra": "codigo: 0592",
    "id": 39,
    "id_cliente": 35,
    "monto_pago_efectivo": null,
    "status": 1,
    "tipo_pago": 2,
  },
},
{
  "id": 58,
  "id_order": Object {
    "created": "23/08/2021 16:37:55",
    "direccion_extra": "codigo: 0592",
    "id": 39,
    "id_cliente": 35,
    "monto_pago_efectivo": null,
    "status": 1,
    "tipo_pago": 2,
  },
},
]
```

This is the Flatlist I am trying to render:

```
<FlatList
    data={item}
    renderItem={({ itemProduct, index }) => <ProductCard item={{itemProduct}} />}}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

However, I cannot receive each of the array's objects in the ProductCard component. Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no `itemProduct` in renderItem function. It is called `item`([FYR](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem)).

You can rename it by

```
    renderItem={({ item: itemProduct, index })
```

BTW, the `<ProductCard item={{itemProduct}} />` should use one {} only unless you want it to be wrapped in an object.

Answer (score 0):

#### Items Array

```
const items = [
  {
    id: 59,
    id_order: {
      created: '23/08/2021 16:37:55',
      direccion_extra: 'codigo: 0592',
      id: 39,
      id_cliente: 35,
      monto_pago_efectivo: null,
      status: 1,
      tipo_pago: 2,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 58,
    id_order: {
      created: '23/08/2021 16:37:55',
      direccion_extra: 'codigo: 0592',
      id: 39,
      id_cliente: 35,
      monto_pago_efectivo: null,
      status: 1,
      tipo_pago: 2,
    },
  },
];
```

#### Flatlist

```
     <FlatList
        data={items}
        renderItem={({ item }) => ( 
          <View>
            <Text>{item.id}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
```

**Note:**

> In FlatList **renderItem** you can't write **itemProduct** you have to write it as **item**